# How to reference a label within a newcommand in LATEX?

Tags: latex

I have created a newcommand \figc to create figures quickly for my document. However, I had trouble referencing it. The document is being compiled successfully but is being shown as Figure (??).

```
\newcommand{\figc}[3]{    
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width={#3}]{figures/{#1}.jpg}
    \caption{{#2}}
    \label{fig:{#1}}
\end{figure}
    fig:{#1}}    ----> However, this part is displayed correctly in the PDF as fig:samplefig


Here is a sample text to reference (Figure \ref{fig:samplefig}).
\figc{samplefig}{Sample Figure}{3in}
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `fig:{#1}` in your `\label`, but instead use `fig:#1`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{float,graphicx}

\newcommand{\figc}[3]{%
  \begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=#3]{#1.jpg}
    \caption{#2}
    \label{fig:#1}
  \end{figure}
  fig:#1% Set the reference as well
}

\begin{document}

Here is a sample text to reference (Figure \ref{fig:example-image}).

\figc{example-image}{Sample Figure}{3in}

\end{document}
```

There's a difference between what is set in a document, and its internal representation. That's why `\label{fig:{abc}}` is different from `\label{fig:abc}`, and therefore can provide an undefined reference.

Comment: Is the order of `\caption` and `\label` important?

Comment: @KcFnMi: Yes. `\label` has to be part of the `\caption` or come after it.

Comment: What it means to "be part of it"?

Comment: @KcFnMi: When you use it like this: `\caption{Your caption\label{label}}`.