# Label not working inside a \newcommand with a custom Float in LaTeX

Tags: latex

I declared a new environment containing a `\caption` and a `\label` so I can make references to it.

In my header:

```
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[name=Tableau]{tableau}
\newenvironment{ptab}{\captionsetup{type=tableau}}{}
```

In my .tex document:

```
\begin{ptab}
    \caption{A caption for my table}
    \label{ptab:myTab}
\end{ptab}

Some text with a reference (Tableau~\ref{ptab:myTab}) % Works fine !
```

The problem: I want to gain some time by declaring a `\newcommand` that could write this for me. But the references in text are not working anymore !

Added in my header:

```
\newcommand{\tabref}[2]{%
    \begin{ptab} 
        \label{#1} 
        \caption{#2} 
    \end{ptab}}
```

In the .tex document:

```
\tabref{ptab:myTab}{A caption for my table}

Some text with a reference (Tableau~\ref{ptab:myTab}) % Not working "(Tableau ??)"
```

I an aware a similar question has already been asked before but it was not concerning new environment.
[How to reference a label within a newcommand in LATEX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49268698/how-to-reference-a-label-within-a-newcommand-in-latex)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the order of `\label{}` and `\caption{}` was inverted. 
It is important since LaTeX needs to create a caption *before* it can be referenced with a label. 
Working code :

```
\newcommand{\tabref}[2]{%
    \begin{ptab}
        \caption{#2} 
        \label{#1}  
    \end{ptab}}

\tabref{ptab:myTab}{A caption for my table}

Some text with a reference (Tableau~\ref{ptab:myTab}) % Now working !
```